# Where is the flaw in my algorithm for consolidating gold mines?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, optimization, complexity-theory

The setup is that, given a list of `N` objects like

```
class Mine
{
    public int Distance { get; set; } // from river
    public int Gold { get; set; } // in tons
}
```

where the cost of moving the gold from one mine to the other is

```
    // helper function for cost of a move
    Func<Tuple<Mine,Mine>, int> MoveCost = (tuple) => 
        Math.Abs(tuple.Item1.Distance - tuple.Item2.Distance) * tuple.Item1.Gold;
```

I want to consolidate the gold into `K` mines.

I've written an algorithm, thought it over many times, and don't understand why it isn't working. Hopefully my comments help out. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Mine
{
    public int Distance { get; set; } // from river
    public int Gold { get; set; } // in tons
}

class Solution 
{
    static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        // helper function for reading lines
        Func<string, int[]> LineToIntArray = (line) => Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(' '), Int32.Parse);

        int[] line1 = LineToIntArray(Console.ReadLine());
        int N = line1[0], // # of mines
            K = line1[1]; // # of pickup locations

        // Populate mine info
        List<Mine> mines = new List<Mine>();
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            int[] line = LineToIntArray(Console.ReadLine());
            mines.Add(new Mine() { Distance = line[0], Gold = line[1] });
        }

        // helper function for cost of a move
        Func<Tuple<Mine,Mine>, int> MoveCost = (tuple) => 
            Math.Abs(tuple.Item1.Distance - tuple.Item2.Distance) * tuple.Item1.Gold;

        // all move combinations
        var moves = from m1 in mines
                    from m2 in mines
                    where !m1.Equals(m2)
                    select Tuple.Create(m1,m2);

        // moves in ascending order of cost
        var ordered = from m in moves
                      orderby MoveCost(m)
                      select m;

        int sum = 0; // running total of move costs
        var spots = Enumerable.Repeat(1, N).ToArray(); // spots[i] = 1 if hasn't been consildated into other mine, 0 otherwise
        var iter = ordered.GetEnumerator();
        while(iter.MoveNext() && spots.Sum() != K)
        {
            var move = iter.Current; // move with next smallest cost
            int i = mines.IndexOf(move.Item1), // index of source mine in move
                j = mines.IndexOf(move.Item2); // index of destination mine in move
            if((spots[i] & spots[j]) == 1) // if the source and destination mines are both unconsolidated
            {
                sum += MoveCost(move); // add this consolidation to the total cost
                spots[i] = 0; // "remove" mine i from the list of unconsolidated mines 
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

An example of a test case I'm failing is

```
3 1
11 3
12 2
13 1
```

My output is

```
3
```

and the correct output is

```
4
```

Comment: Have you tried putting break points in and looking at your data?

Comment: Seems like your code doesn't even compile. Is the line `if(spots[i] & spots[j] == 1)` as intended?

Comment: @LucMorin Ignore that mistake

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand the use of the `spots` variable, which seems to limit, in your sample data, to only 2 sum operations. Can you clarify your idea behind this?

Comment: I have to admit to not understanding the actual goal, so going through your code does indeed yield the "undesired" value, but I'd like to understand how you got to the "desired" value. Can you explain the algorithm in plain old english? Sometimes putting words on an algorithm "forces" the solution out in the open ;-)

Comment: Looks to me this is better handled by a mixed integer programming (MIP) model.

Comment: The greedy algorithm won't always produce optimal results. For example, you have a test case of `3 1 11 4 12 3 13 4`, the answer is 8 - #1 into #2, #3 into #2. The greedy move by your algorithm would be #2 into #1, #3 into #1 with total cost of 11.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer does point out a flaw in the implementation, but it fails to mention that in your code, you aren't actually changing the `Gold` values in the remaining `Mine` objects. So even if you did re-sort the data, it wouldn't help.

Furthermore, at each iteration all you really care about is the *minimum* value. Sorting the entire list of data is overkill. You can just scan it once to find the minimum-valued item.

You also don't really need the separate array of flags. Just maintain your move objects in a list, and after choosing a move, remove the move objects that include the `Mine` you would otherwise have flagged as no longer valid.

Here is a version of your algorithm that incorporates the above feedback:

```
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string input =
@"3 1
11 3
12 2
13 1";
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);

        // helper function for reading lines
        Func<string, int[]> LineToIntArray = (line) => Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(' '), Int32.Parse);

        int[] line1 = LineToIntArray(reader.ReadLine());
        int N = line1[0], // # of mines
            K = line1[1]; // # of pickup locations

        // Populate mine info
        List<Mine> mines = new List<Mine>();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            int[] line = LineToIntArray(reader.ReadLine());
            mines.Add(new Mine() { Distance = line[0], Gold = line[1] });
        }

        // helper function for cost of a move
        Func<Tuple<Mine, Mine>, int> MoveCost = (tuple) =>
            Math.Abs(tuple.Item1.Distance - tuple.Item2.Distance) * tuple.Item1.Gold;

        // all move combinations
        var moves = (from m1 in mines
                    from m2 in mines
                    where !m1.Equals(m2)
                    select Tuple.Create(m1, m2)).ToList();

        int sum = 0, // running total of move costs
            unconsolidatedCount = N;
        while (moves.Count > 0 && unconsolidatedCount != K)
        {
            var move = moves.Aggregate((a, m) => MoveCost(a) < MoveCost(m) ? a : m);

            sum += MoveCost(move); // add this consolidation to the total cost
            move.Item2.Gold += move.Item1.Gold;
            moves.RemoveAll(m => m.Item1 == move.Item1 || m.Item2 == move.Item1);
            unconsolidatedCount--;    
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Moves: " + sum);
    }
```

Without more detail in your question, I can't guarantee that this actually meets the specification. But it does produce the value `4` for the `sum`. :)

Comment: Doesn't satisfy all the test cases here https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mining?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Comment: @user6048670: Stack Overflow isn't the place for you to have someone write code for some third-party web site. All I can offer is the fix for _your_ code, based on the specifications you've provided in _your_ question. The above addresses the error in your implementation of _your_ understanding of the problem, but it's not possible to address that understanding. You would need to provide a lot more detail, and frankly having done so you'd probably find it makes the question far too broad to be a good Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @user6048670: you can provide additional test cases in your question if you like, but without a better description of the problem you're actually supposed to be solving and _why_ the "correct" answers are in fact correct, it's not possible to provide a better answer.

Comment: There's a flaw in this algorithm as well, because you don't know which move would be better, to put #2 into #3, or #3 into #2, if they have the same amount of gold. Say the test data is `3 1 11 3 12 1 13 1`, the proper consolidation would be #3 into #2, then #2 into #1, or #3 into #1, #2 into #1 for a total cost of 3, the algorithm can produce a #2 into #3, then #3 into #1 for 5 total cost.

Comment: @Vesper: you may be right, but "this algorithm" is simply the correct implementation of the algorithm that was intended in the code given in the question. I didn't change the design, just the implementation. The OP would need to provide a complete specification if they want a complete answer. So far, the only "specification" given was "it should return the value `4`". It's not even stated that the result should optimize anything or if so, what should be optimized (number of moves? cost of moves? cost _after_ consolidation?).

Answer (score 0):

When you consolidate mine *i* into mine *j*, the amount of gold in the mine *j* is increased. This makes consolidations from mine *j* to other mines more expensive potentially making the ordering of the mines by the move cost invalid. To fix this, you could re-sort the list of mines at the beginning of each iteration of your while-loop.