# How am I getting an out-of-range exception here?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures

Been looking at this for a while and can't figure it out. As the comments below point out, the indices in question are in the list.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Mine
{
    public int Distance { get; set; }
    public int Gold { get; set; }
}

public class Move
{
    public int SourceIndex { get; set; }
    public int DestinationIndex { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }   
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var mines = new List<Mine> () {
            new Mine() { Distance = 10, Gold = 1 },
            new Mine() { Distance = 20, Gold = 2 },
            new Mine() { Distance = 25, Gold = 1 }
        };

        // Cost of consolidating the gold from mines[i1] to mines[i2]
        Func<int,int,int> Cost = (i1, i2) => Math.Abs(mines[i1].Distance - mines[i2].Distance) * mines[i1].Gold;

        // Number of mines to consolidate the gold into 
        int k = 1;


        var bestMove = new Move() { SourceIndex = -1, DestinationIndex = -1, Cost = Int32.MaxValue }; 

        // total cost
        int sum = 0;

        while(mines.Count != k)
        {
            var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, mines.Count).ToArray();
            for(int i = 0, j = 1; j < indices.Length; ++i, ++j)
            {
                int cost_ij = Cost(i,j);
                if(cost_ij < bestMove.Cost)
                {
                    bestMove.SourceIndex = i; 
                    bestMove.DestinationIndex = j; 
                    bestMove.Cost = cost_ij;
                }

                int cost_ji = Cost(j,i);
                if(cost_ji < bestMove.Cost)
                {
                    bestMove.SourceIndex = j; 
                    bestMove.DestinationIndex = i; 
                    bestMove.Cost = cost_ji;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("bestMove.SourceIndex = {0}, bestMove.DestinationIndex = {1}", bestMove.SourceIndex, bestMove.DestinationIndex); // prints "bestMove.SourceIndex = 2, bestMove.DestinationIndex = 1"
            sum += bestMove.Cost;
            mines[bestMove.DestinationIndex].Gold += mines[bestMove.SourceIndex].Gold; // this is throwing an exception "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."
            mines.RemoveAt(bestMove.SourceIndex); 

        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hYa3A0

It makes no sense because at the time the

```
            Console.WriteLine("bestMove.SourceIndex = {0}, bestMove.DestinationIndex = {1}", bestMove.SourceIndex, bestMove.DestinationIndex); // prints "bestMove.SourceIndex = 2, bestMove.DestinationIndex = 1"
            sum += bestMove.Cost;
            mines[bestMove.DestinationIndex].Gold += mines[bestMove.SourceIndex].Gold; // this is throwing an exception "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."
            mines.RemoveAt(bestMove.SourceIndex);
```

lines are run for the first time,

```
bestMove.DestinationIndex = 2
bestMove.DestinationIndex = 1
```

and

```
mines.Count = 3
```

Maybe I'm just crazy.

Comment: The question looks surprisingly similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711479/where-is-the-flaw-in-my-algorithm-for-consolidating-gold-mines/38711949
Is this an assignment?

Comment: You are using the same instance of bestMove, you need to reset its fields after every while loop (i guess).

Comment: What is the value of `bestMove.DestinationIndex` and `bestMove.SourceIndex` when that line executes?  That will tell you why you are getting the exception.

Comment: When I run the code, the value of `bestMove.SourceIndex` is 2 when the exception occurs.  At that time, the `mines` list only has 2 instances in it so the only valid indices are 0 and 1.  2 is clearly out of range.

Answer (score 2):

indices is a zero based index.

Change the for loop to this:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 1; j < indices.Length-1; ++i, ++j)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your counter j.
j gets assigned 4 at one point which exceeds the size of your mines collection(3).

Change the first line in while loop to this:

```
var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, mines.Count - 1).ToArray();
```