# What is the flaw in this algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, optimization, greedy

I'm trying to figure out what the problem is with the implementation of my algorithm for consolidating `N` mines of gold into `K` at the least cost possible, where the cost of consilidating the gold from one mine to another is equal to the distance between them times the weight of gold in the source mine.

**Example of my algorithm:**

Let's say we have the following `N=3` mines

```
A = { Distance = 10, Gold = 2 }
B = { Distance = 12, Gold = 1 }
C = { Distance = 15, Gold = 1 }
```

and we want to consolidate the gold into `K=1` mines. The costs of consolidating the gold the first time are the following.

```
Cost(B,A) = |12 - 10| * 1 = 2
Cost(B,C) = |12 - 15| * 1 = 3
Cost(C,B) = |15 - 12| * 1 = 3
Cost(A,B) = |10 - 12| * 2 = 4
Cost(C,A) = |15 - 10| * 1 = 5
Cost(A,C) = |10 - 15| * 2 = 10
```

So let's make our first consolidation to be to move the gold from `B` to `A`.

Our total cost is `2`, our mines look like

```
A = { Distance = 10, Gold = 3 }
C = { Distance = 15, Gold = 1 }
```

and our costs in order are

```
Cost(C,A) = |15 - 10| * 1 = 5
Cost(A,C) = |10 - 15| * 3 = 15
```

(Note how we removed from our list of costs any that involved `B`, since it is now gone.)

Our next consolidation is, again, the first element in the ordered list of costs.

After making that consolidation, moving the fold from `C` to `A`, our total cost is now `2 + 5 = 7`, our mines are

```
A = { Distance = 10, Gold = 4 }
```

Because that group is of size `K=1`, we're done.

**Generalization pseudo-code:**

```
 Mines = list of mines, 
 K = desired number mines,
 sum = 0
 while(Mines.Count != K)
 {
     Find m1,m2 in Mines such that Cost(m1,m2) is minimized

     sum += Cost(m1,m2)

     m2.Gold += m1.Gold

     Mines.Remove(m1)

 }
```

Can someone tell me why that doesn't work?

Comment: Related (followup?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711479/where-is-the-flaw-in-my-algorithm-for-consolidating-gold-mines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be from: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mining.

This can also be modeled easily using a Mixed Integer Programming model. Given data `c(i,j)` (cost of moving all gold from i to j) and `k` (number of consolidation points) we can write:

[image]

Here `x(i,j)` is 1 if we move things from i to j (and 0 otherwise). `y(j)=1` if we selected mine j as consolidation point (and 0 otherwise). This model can be solved with any MIP solver.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is a [**greedy algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm). Making the locally optimal choice is not always the best.

Here is a situation where you algorithm doesn't find the best solution

```
A = { Distance = 10, Gold = 1 }
B = { Distance = 0, Gold = 10 }
C = { Distance = 15, Gold = 2 }
```

An intuitive guess at the correct solution would be to move `A` and `C` to `B`, as `B` has a lot of gold which would be hard to move. However, your algorithm first makes the *locally optimum* move of `A` to `C`. It then must follow with `C` to `B` for a total cost of `5 + 45 = 50`

A better solution is to move `A` to `B` then `C` to `B`, for a cost of `10 + 30 = 40`

Solving these kinds of problems is not always easy, one method is to perform a [**brute-force search**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search), but this can become intractable if the number of mines is large